# Is Stylus render function Synchronous?

Tags: stylus

I'm compiling my Stylus `.styl` stylesheets with its JavaScript API: http://learnboost.github.io/stylus/docs/js.html

```
  var stylus = require('../')
    , str = require('fs').readFileSync(__dirname + '/test.styl', 'utf8');

  stylus(str)
    .set('filename', __dirname + '/test.styl')
    .import('mixins/vendor')
    .render(function(err, css){
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log(css);
  });
```

It doesn't mention whether the callback it's using is Synchronous or Asynchronous. Although in my experience it *seems* to be Synchronous but I'm not sure. Is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `render` function is pseudo-asynchronous because it accepts a callback, but all calls inside the function are actually synchronous. There is also a fully synchronous version of this function (if you don't provide the callback):

```
var styl = stylus(str)
  .set('filename', __dirname + '/test.styl')
  .import('mixins/vendor');

console.log(styl.render()); // outputs compiled css
```